# Write unique values in Spark while keeping old values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark job which is time scheduled to be executed.

When I write the result DataFrame to a **Data Target** (S3, HDFS, DB...), I want that what Spark writes is not duplicated for a specific column.

**EXAMPLE:**

Let's say that `MY_ID` is the unique column.

1st execution:

```
--------------
|MY_ID|MY_VAL|
--------------
|  1  |   5  |
|  2  |   9  |
|  3  |   6  |
--------------
```

2nd execution:

```
--------------
|MY_ID|MY_VAL|
--------------
|  2  |   9  |
|  3  |   2  |
|  4  |   4  |
--------------
```

What I am expecting to find in the **Data Target** after the 2 executions is something like this:

```
--------------
|MY_ID|MY_VAL|
--------------
|  1  |   5  |
|  2  |   9  |
|  3  |   6  |
|  4  |   4  |
--------------
```

Where the expected output is the result of the first execution with the results of the second execution appended. In case the value for `MY_ID` already exists, the old one is kept, discarding the results of new executions (in this case the 2nd execution wants to write for `MY_ID` 3 the `MY_VAL` 9. Since that this record already exists from the 1st execution, the new record is discarded).

So the `distinct()` function is not enough to guarantee this condition. The uniqueness of the column `MY_ID` should be kept even in the dumped output.

Is there any solution that can guarantee this property at reasonable computational costs? (It is basically the same idea of `UNIQUE` in relational Databases.)

Answer (score 0):

You can to do `fullOuterJoin` on first & second iteration.

```
val joined = firstIteration.join(secondIteration, Seq("MY_ID"), "fullouter")

scala> joined.show
+-----+------+------+
|MY_ID|MY_VAL|MY_VAL|
+-----+------+------+
|    1|     5|  null|
|    3|     6|     2|
|    4|  null|     4|
|    2|     9|     9|
+-----+------+------+
```

From the resultant table, if firstIteration's `MY_VAL` has value, you can use it as it is. Else if its `null` (indicates that the key occurs only in second iteration). use the value from secondIteration's `MY_VAL`.

```
scala> joined.withColumn("result", when(firstIteration.col("MY_VAL").isNull, secondIteration.col("MY_VAL"))
        .otherwise(firstIteration.col("MY_VAL")))
       .drop("MY_VAL")
       .show
+-----+------+
|MY_ID|result|
+-----+------+
|    1|     5|
|    3|     6|
|    4|     4|
|    2|     9|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that `firstIteration` would need to be something like `spark.read.[source](parameters)`. Which means introducing an overhead for reading the "persisted source". Plus does not scale very well, because I am expecting that the described steps can be executed over and over (just like updating a relational DB). I was looking for a solution out of the box like `UNIQUE` columns in Relational DB, which is already implemented and highly optimised. Not a "workaround" which obtains the same result but with more expensive computational cost

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether you are using Scala or Python but have a look at the `dropDuplicates` function that allow you the specify one or more columns:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset